# The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'

Tags: angularjs, node.js, module, angular-cli, angular-compiler-cli

When trying **npm start** or **ng serve** it shows the error like this :

```
The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'    
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed.     Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'    
    at Object.     (/home/jsnsree/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules//src/index.js:14:11)    
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)    
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)    
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)    
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)    
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)    
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)    
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)    
at Object.     (/home/jsnsree/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/eject.js:10:19)    
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)    
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)    
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)    
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)    
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)    
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)    
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

And the ng versoin in my application shows :

```
@angular/cli: 1.3.2    
node: 6.11.2     
os: linux x64     
@angular/animations: error     
@angular/common: error     
@angular/compiler: error     
@angular/core: error     
@angular/forms: error     
@angular/http: error     
@angular/platform-browser: error     
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: error     
@angular/platform-server: error     
@angular/router: error     
@angular/cli: error     
@angular/compiler-cli: error
```

I tried to remove and reinstall angular/cli but it doesn't make any changes:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing your CLI.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

delete node_modules from your project 
and run

```
npm install
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
npm install @angular/{animations,common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router}
```